# Bullet lists do not display in the selected container

Tags: javascript, html, css

These are my full codes for my home page. Here, I have encountered that the lists that I created in the `tabcontent` class do not seem to be displayed in the output/display box. At first, I encountered that the lists do not display in bullet from but was displayed next to each other. So, I modified/added class for the `ul` and `li` for the navigation bar and it started to display in the list form. However, the list of bullets do not seem to display correctly inside the `tabcontent` box.

```js
function openTest(evt, testName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(testName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #d62929;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.ul1 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.li1 {
  float: left;
}

.li1 a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 22px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.li1 a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #c12525;
  color: white;
}

.li1.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  min-width: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #c12525;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.active {
  background-color: #d62929;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  ul1 li1,
  ul1 li1 {
    float: none;
  }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  footer {
    -webkit-order: 3;
    order: 3;
  }
}

footer {
  background: #aaa;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  clear: both;
  /* clearing floating affects from both left,right sides */
}

.footp {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: top;
}


/* Style the tab */

div.tab {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

div.tab button {
  display: block;
  background-color: inherit;
  color: black;
  padding: 22px 16px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

div.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current "tab button" class */

div.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  float: inherit;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 90%;
  border-left: none;
  height: 320px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <ul class="ul1">
    <li class="li1"><a class="active" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown li1">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Capacity Study</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="mainFrame.html">Conduct Study</a>
        <a href="report.html">Reports</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="li1"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

  <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTest(event, 'Full DRC')" id="defaultOpen">Full DRC</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTest(event, 'QDRC')">QDRC</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTest(event, 'Cold Screening')">Cold Screening</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTest(event, 'Hot Screening')">Hot Screening</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTest(event, 'VCT Room')">VCT Room</button>
  </div>

  <div id="Full DRC" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Full DRC</h3>
    <p>Test Points Tested</p>
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="QDRC" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>QDRC</h3>
    <p>Test Points Tested</p>
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="Cold Screening" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Cold Screening</h3>
    <p>Test Points Tested</p>
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="Hot Screening" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Hot Screening</h3>
    <p>Test Points Tested</p>
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="VCT Room" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Room</h3>
    <p>Test Points Tested</p>
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
  <div>
    <footer>
      <p class="footp">&copy;All rights reserved.</p>
      <p class="footp">|</p>
      <p class="footp">Internal Use Only</p>
      <p class="footp">|</p>
      <p class="footp">Maintained By :</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding `ul { display: inline-block; }` to your CSS.

Comment: @AndroidNoobie Thank you so much. It works perfectly !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block;`

```js
function openTest(evt, testName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(testName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #d62929;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.ul1 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.li1 {
  float: left;
}

.li1 a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 22px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.li1 a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #c12525;
  color: white;
}

.li1.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  min-width: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #c12525;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.active {
  background-color: #d62929;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  ul1 li1,
  ul1 li1 {
    float: none;
  }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  footer {
    -webkit-order: 3;
    order: 3;
  }
}

footer {
  background: #aaa;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  clear: both;
  /* clearing floating affects from both left,right sides */
}
ul{
   display:inline-block;
}
.footp {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: top;
}


/* Style the tab */

div.tab {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

div.tab button {
  display: block;
  background-color: inherit;
  color: black;
  padding: 22px 16px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

div.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current "tab button" class */

div.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  float: inherit;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 90%;
  border-left: none;
  height: 320px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <ul class="ul1">
    <li class="li1"><a class="active" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown li1">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Capacity Study</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="mainFrame.html">Conduct Study</a>
        <a href="report.html">Reports</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="li1"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

  <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTest(event, 'Full DRC')" id="defaultOpen">Full DRC</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTest(event, 'QDRC')">QDRC</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTest(event, 'Cold Screening')">Cold Screening</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTest(event, 'Hot Screening')">Hot Screening</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTest(event, 'VCT Room')">VCT Room</button>
  </div>

  <div id="Full DRC" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Full DRC</h3>
    <p>Test Points Tested</p>
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="QDRC" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>QDRC</h3>
    <p>Test Points Tested</p>
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="Cold Screening" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Cold Screening</h3>
    <p>Test Points Tested</p>
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="Hot Screening" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Hot Screening</h3>
    <p>Test Points Tested</p>
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="VCT Room" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Room</h3>
    <p>Test Points Tested</p>
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
  <div>
    <footer>
      <p class="footp">&copy;All rights reserved.</p>
      <p class="footp">|</p>
      <p class="footp">Internal Use Only</p>
      <p class="footp">|</p>
      <p class="footp">Maintained By :</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated below css

```
.tabcontent {
    /* float: inherit; */
    padding: 0px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 60%;
    border-left: none;
    height: 320px;
    float: left;
}
```

Link: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaanhaitojahanhai/farL09om/)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. The issue is when I change to `float: left` the box tend to stick to the footer. Therefore, `float: inherit` would be the best choice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @cerberus99 Please take a look https://jsfiddle.net/jaanhaitojahanhai/farL09om/1/